# Find the limit of the sequence using the definition of a limit only

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence $\sqrt{\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}}$ and I figured out that its limit is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ using the limit laws, but I can't come up with the right evaluation that would allow me to find the limit without any laws using the definition only. I tried the simplest estimates like increasing the numerator or decreasing the denominator, Bernoulli's inequality, but it seems that they don't work here, at least I didn't succeed. What else can I do to evaluate this sequence with a simpler one to set an $\epsilon$ and an N?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Do you *have* to prove it using the $\varepsilon-N$ definition?

Comment: Yes, by definition I meant the $\epsilon$-N definition, sorry for not clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

If $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\in\Bbb N$, then\begin{align}\left|\sqrt{\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}}-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right|&=\frac{\left|\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}-\frac12\right|}{\sqrt{\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}}+\frac1{\sqrt2}}\\&<\sqrt2\frac{3n^4+2}{2n^8-6n^4}\\&<\sqrt2\frac{3n^4}{2n^8}\\&=\frac3{2\sqrt2n^4}\end{align}and$$\frac3{2\sqrt2n^4}<\varepsilon\iff n^4>\frac3{2\sqrt2\varepsilon}.$$So, take$$N=\left\lceil\sqrt[4]{\frac3{2\sqrt2\varepsilon}}\right\rceil.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sqrt{\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}}-\sqrt \frac  1 2=\frac {2(n^8+2)-2n^8+6n^4} {[\sqrt{\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}}+\sqrt \frac  1 2] [ 2(n^{8}-6n^{4}]}$. Now use the fact that the donominator exceeds$2^{-1/2}n^{5} $ for $n$ sufficiently large. ( $2(n^{8}-6n^{4})\geq 2n^{5}-12 n^{4}>n^{5}$ if $n>12$) Now you can easily complete the $\epsilon -N$ proof.

Comment: [$N=10\sqrt 2 /\epsilon$ will do].

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sqrt{\frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}} \to \frac{\sqrt 2}2 \iff \frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4} \to\frac12 \iff  \frac{n^8+2}{2n^8-6n^4}-\frac12=\frac{3 n^4 + 2}{2 n^4 (n^4 - 3)} \to 0$$

and for any $\varepsilon >0$

$$\frac{3 n^4 + 2}{2 n^4 (n^4 - 3)}\le\frac{5 n^4 }{2 n^4 (n^4 - 3)}=\frac{5  }{2  (n^4 - 3)}<\varepsilon \iff n^4>\frac 5{2\varepsilon}+3 \iff n>N=\sqrt[4]{\frac 5{2\varepsilon}+3}$$